# Is the word "what" a pronoun in the question: Do you know what I mean?

Tags: relative-pronouns, interrogatives

Is the word "what" a pronoun in the question: Do you know what I mean? I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know **what** I mean?

The "standard" classification for *what* in this context—a 'free' or 'fused' relative clause—is **relative pronoun**.

This classification ignores (or begs) a lot of very important questions such as

- whether this *what* is the same word as interrogative *what?* in *What do you mean?*
- whether this *what* is the same word as adjectival or determinative *what* in *What song the Syrens sang or what name Achilles assumed when he hid himself among women, though puzzling questions, are not beyond all conjecture.*
- whether this *what* is in fact not a pronoun but a fused-head determiner
- whether this *what* is properly classified as relative given that it can head only *fused* relative clauses and not (except in dialect use) the more central *bound* relative clauses

If you're really interested in any of these, throw up another question. But if all you care about is what answer to give on an exam, say "relative pronoun" and move onto something more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I read this as indicating another phrase, I forget the exact term for this kind of sentence. It almost helps to put it in parentheses.

Do you know (what I mean)?

In that sense, what is the indicator that the phrase is dependent. That makes it seem like a preposition, but it is generally considered a pronoun, because sentences like "What does that mean?" make "what" the object of the sentence, like a noun.

Comment: Nope, it's a pronoun.  "The thing or things that...": "***What** I mean*" = "***The thing (or things) that** I mean*".

Comment: I'm sorry, You are correct. I should have looked it up.

Comment: Fix your answer.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Learn not to be rude.  Short imperatives can be quite distasteful.  (My use of a short imperative was intentional) :)

Comment: A smiley helps, don't it?